# What version of Crystal Reports uses 13.0.2000?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I'm been tasked with making some small changes to an ASP.NET Web Forms app written some years ago, whose implementer is no longer with us and left some years back.

There's 6 reports in this app, all of which use some version of Crystal Reports. When I look at the `Web.Config` file I see things like `CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0` and `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engineer, Version=13.0.2000.0`.

What version of Crystal is that? If it's Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010, can I install that onto my PC to use it with VS 2013? I don't have VS 2010 nor do we have access to it.

Comment: This will help.As i was searching for the error on new setup system. [https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/#how-to-install-crystal-report-runtime](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/#how-to-install-crystal-report-runtime)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find those files here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

It works with versions of Visual Studio from 2010 to 2015. The file versions are different for each service pack, but the reference version is still `13.0.2000.0`.

Answer (score 5):

13.0.2000.0 is the assembly version. You'd see this in the GAC.

You need to make sure you download the correct CR version. 
You can use VS2013, you need to refer to [this](http://scn.sap.com/thread/3440443) 
You basically need SP 9 upwards update. As mentioned in other answer [this](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) link should help.
32 bit version available at:
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_14.zip

64 bit version available at: 
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_13_0_14.zip

Comment: You can see this link: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-download-for-visual-studio/

Comment: links are broken!

Answer (score 0):

goto  publish-> prequisites-> include all the prequisite--> then publish.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Fixed with the installation of version 13.0.19.2312

Answer (score 0):

Please note, **Crystal Reports** uses **13.0.2000** work with **VS2017** too.
Update the below code in Web config file and download and add the **CrystalDecisions DDL** Reference the below  to project to fix the issue

```
New ReportClass()
<dependentAssembly>
   <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
   <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Remove the space near to bracket, please