# Crystal Report not working in client machine. Which runtime version should I install

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I use Visual Studio 2010 with DOT NET version 4.0.
My Database is `MySQL`.

Crystal Report installed in my system...

[image: CRV]

My OS is Windows 7 64 bit.

While seeing in Visual Studio, the version of Crystal Report is showing 13.0.2000.0

[image: cr]

My application `app.config` is like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

---

Now the Client System is also Windows 7 64 bit. I installed DOT NET 4.0 and `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0` in client system.

While executing my application an error shows...

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.CommLayer, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

And the application stopped working.

I installed Crystal Report `v.13.0.14.1720`, but failed.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855903/what-version-of-crystal-reports-uses-13-0-2000). I installed `v.13.0.20.2399` (**Support Pack 20**) but the error resumes.

I did not find `v.13.0.2000.0` download from scn.sap.com.

**Which version of crystal report I should install in client system?**

If this error is for `DOT NET` ([Ref. from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34658073/crystal-report-not-opening-in-client-machine)), then how should I resolve it?

Comment: Have you tried installing via nuget? From there it can get any dependencies too if it needs them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

In my development system, I am using Crystal Report **`v.13.0.14.1720`**.

**My first fault:**

My application build is **`x86`**. But I installed the **`64bit`** msi of the same version in the client PC.

As per [SAP](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3950403), Crystal Report runtime is platform specific (i.e. **`x86`** or **`x64`**) for application setting and not the OS specific.

So If anybody builds the application in **`x86`** (32bit) then the 32bit msi should be installed in client pc. On the other hand, if the application build is **`x64`** (64bit) then the 64bit msi should be installed in client pc.

**My second fault:**

Being failed repeatedly, I installed **`v.13.0.20.2399`** in the client pc.

Note that, **`v.13.0.14.1720`** is service pack 14 and **`v.13.0.20.2399`** is service pack 20. My app is compiled using service pack 14. So I have to distribute the **`SP14`** runtime version. This is why my application crashed.

So **we have to install 32bit(for 32bit application) or 64bit(for 64bit application) msi of the same service pack that is installed in development system.**

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there a difference between Target CPU X86 and platform X64 in configuration manager ?